# Dynamic SQL query - how do I add an int to the code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sql-injection

Consider:

```
Declare @stringsvar varchar(1000)
Declare @Emp_id int 
DECLARE  @strvar SYSNAME = 'Employee_test'

SET @stringsvar = ('select * from' + ' ' + @strvar + ' where emp_id' + ' =' + @Emp_id)
Print @stringsvar
```

The above query is giving an error as mentioned below:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value 'select * from Employee_test where emp_id =' to
>   data type int.

What needs to be done in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[George's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241608/22336) does solve your problem, but it leaves you wide open to [SQL injection attacks](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

While converting an `INT` to a `VARCHAR 11` is likely not going to cause any issues, [sysname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server) is the equivalent of an `NVARCHAR 128`, and you can jam a lot of extra code in there.

To make your code totally safe, you'd want to do this:

```
DECLARE @stringsvar NVARCHAR(1000) = '';
DECLARE @Emp_id INT = 1;
DECLARE @strvar sysname = N'Employee_test';

SET @stringsvar = ( N'select * from ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(@strvar) 
                    + N' where emp_id' 
                    + N' = @iEmp_id' );

PRINT @stringsvar;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stringsvar, 
                       N'@iEmp_id INT', 
                       @iEmp_id = @Emp_id;
```

Using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to issue parameterized dynamic SQL, and [quotename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to make the table name non-executable code is a much safer choice.

For a little more reference, I'd suggest heading over here: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 6):

The issue is down to [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In this case, the `INT` data type is of higher precedence, as such the `VARCHAR` datatype is converted (or attempted to be converted) in this case to the data type of higher precedence (`INT`).

A simple CAST to `VARCHAR` should solve this as below

```
 Declare @stringsvar varchar(1000)
 Declare @Emp_id int 
 DECLARE  @strvar SYSNAME = 'Employee_test'

SET @stringsvar = ('select * from' + ' ' + QUOTENAME(@strvar) + ' where emp_id' + ' =' + CAST(@Emp_id AS VARCHAR(11)))
Print @stringsvar
```